# Why does a USB Numeric Keypad generating two events under Mac OS X when NumLock is on?

Tags: python, macos, pyside, keypress, num-lock

I have just acquired a Compucessory 2-port USB numeric keypad (Model: 34222).

Under Linux, using Python 2 and PySide, it works correctly regardless of the NumLock setting.  (It generates different values, but it only generates one value per keypress.)

Under Mac OS X (Sierra), when NumLock is off, all is well. When it is on, every keypress generates the correct value (e.g. 49) but then this is followed by 16777227 which is the value for the "5" key when the NumLock is on.

Here's a whittled-down version of the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function

import sys

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui  import *

class QGV(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QGV, self).__init__(parent)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 200, 200, self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):

        deg = {55: 225,       56: 270,       57: 315,        # 7   8   9
               52: 180,                      54:   0,        # 4  (5)  6
               49: 135,       50:  90,       51:  45,        # 1   2   3
               16777232: 225, 16777235: 270, 16777238: 315,  # 7   8   9
               16777234: 180,                16777236:   0,  # 4  (5)  6
               16777233: 135, 16777237:  90, 16777239:  45}  # 1   2   3

        if event.isAutoRepeat():
            return

        k = event.key()
        if k == Qt.Key_Escape:
            QApplication.closeAllWindows()

        if k in deg:
            print("Set:     {0:3d} degrees ({1:8d})".format(deg[k], k))
        elif k in (53, 16777227):
            print("Reset:               ({0:8d})".format(k))
        else:
            print("Ignored:             ({0:8d})".format(k))
        super(QGV, self).keyPressEvent(event)


def main():
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    qgv = QGV()
    qgv.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What's the output of the above program? `16777227` is `0x100000b` so looks like a flag is set in the upper bits to indicate num lock status?

Comment: @PeterGibson On Linux, it outputs only one line per keypress (49-57 for NumLock off or one of the 167772* for NumLock on), but on Mac OS X, it outputs two lines per keypress: first a value between 49 and 57, followed by 16777227. I only want the first value.

Comment: Does it behave normally as a keypad on OS X? (In other applications)

Comment: @PeterGibson I only tried it in Bash, and regardless of the NumLock, it gave me the digit that I pressed. (It did not interpret any of the keys as cursor-keys, or other "shifted" markings on the keys.) But it didn't send two characters, in either case (pun intended).